# What is the Visual Studio search/replace free entry "look in" field for?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 "Find and Replace" window, you can freely type anything you want into the "Look in" field:

[image]

The preset dropdown values are things like:

- Current Window
- All open documents
- Entire solution
- etc.

What is the purpose of allowing typing in this field? What could I possibly type in here which would make any sense?

And if I do type something like "foo bar" in there, what is the behavior when one of the "Find..." buttons is clicked? It seems to just search normally - maybe in the current solution (??).

---

Note - it even seems like mistaken entries [can get stuck in there](https://superuser.com/questions/403245/how-can-i-remove-items-from-the-look-in-combo-box-in-visual-studios-find-an).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That allows one to specify directories. Or even multiple directories. Or even combinations of built in locations and directories. Separate each location with a semicolon.

Example:

```
Entire Solution;C:\Source\18.1
```

Then to remove an entry, click on the ... button. This will bring up a dialog box titled "Choose Search Folders". Then on the right hand side, selected the entry you wish to remove and then click on the button that looks like a less- than, or left-angle bracket. This will remove the entry.

[image]